# Question related to voice

Tags: passive-voice

I have to solve this problem.
**Let's play a game**.
And I have to change this question into passive voice.

Comment: You can't. In essence, if not in detail, this is exactly the same question as [It's related to voice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254020/its-related-to-voice)—and the essential answer is the same as there.

Comment: Can you explain **why** you have to change this to passive?  Are you being paid to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  The main verb in this sentence is "Let", and it is being used in an imperative form (but in the well-known idiom "let's" which is used to raise a suggestion)

You can't change imperative to passive and you can't change "Let's" sentences to passive.

The infinitve clause "play a game" has a verb (play) and object (a game) and this can be put into a passive form:  "a game be played", so

> Let a game be played (by us)

Is a correctly formed sentence.   It is just not a very common expression, so don't actually say this.